# header(Content-type: image/jpeg) not working

Tags: php

I have written some code to resize an image (followed PHP manual) but I cannot get the image to display. I know the image data exists as I can see it when I echo the $thumb but I can't seem to get the actual image to display.

This is the code I have used:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$image = $row["image"];
echo $image;
echo $row["name"];

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image);

$newwidth = $width * 0.1;
$newheight = $height * 0.1;

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);

imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0,0,0,0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($thumb), true);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo imagejpeg($thumb);
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Remove the `echo`. `imagejpeg($thumb)` will be enough (if $thumb is a proper image resource)

Comment: Take a look at you actually send out, either by saving into a file or by using a network sniffer. When something does not work always look exactly at what is actually being produced, don't stay on a meta level ("does not work"). Is the content that is sent _really_ a jpeg? No. And you can see that if you look at the content.

Comment: Tried removing the echo but then I just get the data not the actual image but thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by using a 'network sniffer' I am fairly new to PHP so I don't have that much experience. The original file is a jpeg and I am assuming that the code (taken from the PHP manual) creates another jpeg.

Answer (score 2):

1. Delete `\t` from `$thumb`
2. You can't print strings in a jpeg file. So delete `echo $image;` and `echo $row["name"];` .
3. You can put this code in another file and use it as image .

index.php :
`$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);`
`$image = $row["image"];`
`echo $image;`
`echo $row["name"];`
`echo '<img src="image.php">';`

image.php :

```
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $image = $row["image"];

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image);
    $newwidth = $width * 0.1;
    $newheight = $height * 0.1;
    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
    imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0,0,0,0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

    $h = str_replace('\t','',$thumb);

    header('Content-Length: '.strlen($h), true);
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    imagejpeg($thumb);
```

Comment: I will try your suggestion out Thank you

Comment: Thank you all for your help I have managed to solve the problem now by using a function that simply takes the image size and sets the width and height properties of the img tag to a proportional size. I know its not elegant but the images are downloaded from a database so I already know that they are jpegs so no worries about the user trying to download other file types.

Comment: You're welcome :) please mark this answer as accepted , if the answer is correct. thanks a lot